# Challenge: How to turn an NSArray of numbers into an English-readable list

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsarray, integer

I'm looking for a nice clean routine for turning an NSArray containing NSNumbers (integers) into a nice English-readable string. For example, I want to change this:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:12],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:33], nil];
```

into this:

> 5, 7, 12 and 13.

Is there any nice way of doing this without hideous if statement logic? I'm sure it can be done with a regular expression, but is that possible in pre-iOS 4 code?

Thanks! :)

:-Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look mom, no ifs!

```
NSString *seps[] = {@" and ",@"",@", ",nil,nil,@", "}, *o = @".", *sep = o;
for ( NSNumber *n in [arr reverseObjectEnumerator] ) {
   o = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",n,sep = seps[[sep length]],o];
}

NSLog(@"out: %@",o);
```

output:

```
out: 5, 7, 12 and 33.
```

but why?

**edit** here is an understandable version with no "huge if/else construct"

```
NSString *out = @"";  // no numbers = empty string
NSString *sep = @"."; // the separator first used is actually the ending "."
for ( NSNumber *n in [arr reverseObjectEnumerator] )
{
    out = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",n,sep,out];
    if ( [sep isEqualToString:@"."] ) // was the separator the ending "." ?
    {
        sep = @" and "; // if so, put in the last separator " and "
    } else {
        sep = @", ";    // otherwise, use separator ", "
    }
}
```

This will output strings like

```
0 elements: ""        (i.e. empty)
1 element:  "33."
2 elements: "12 and 33."
3 elements: "7, 12 and 33."
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks :)

It's for a multitouch interface, where the user can select different items on the screen simultaneously. So I can write into a label in plain English, which numbers are being selected.

Congratulations, you win... My admiration! ;-)

Comment: *don't you ever, ever put this in a real project* ;-)

Comment: because I made it with the purpose of being hard to understand. What I really meant to say is why no "if"? This is the typical case for an if statement; for **if** you're adding the last element, you take separator `" and "` and **else** you take separator `", "`. I think any other way will be harder to understand on the long run.

Comment: Yes I can appreciate that. I guess I meant I didn't want HUUUGE loads of statement logic if..then...else...if...then etc if I could avoid it! :)

Comment: @Joe: I added a version which you must be able to understand, and has only *one* `if`.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray *numbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:12],
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:33], nil];
NSArray *first = [numbers subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [numbers count]-1)];
NSString *joined = [[first componentsJoinedByString:@", "] stringByAppendingFormat:(([first count] > 0) ? @"and %@" : @"%@"), [numbers lastObject]];
```

Comment: Don't know if it works but it looks like it should. Pretty awesome :D

Comment: If this is for debugging purposes, don't forget about `[anArray description]`.

Comment: This results in *"and 5"* for an array containing only 5.

Comment: I hate to be picky... but ;) I forgot to mention that it needs to work even if the Array is empty... This version crashes if it's empty :(

Comment: but I should be checking the array first anyway so it's okay :P

will this version be any better than the one above? That's the question :)

Comment: @Joe It's much more readable, which in most cases would constitute "better". :)